# How can a java function be called in javascript?

Tags: java, javascript

I have a java application that must make use of a html file that has javascript code in it.

I have a java class that looks like this

```
package myPackage.utils;

public class ReturnDemo{

    public static double GetSumOfValues(double value1, double value2)
    {
        return value1+value2;
    }

}
```

What i would like is to be able to do something like this:

```
//value1 and value2 are obtained dinamically
var MyValue = ReturnDemo.GetSumOfValues(value1, value2)
```

I have searched the internet but was overwhelmed with answers for the case of using javascript in a client application and java in the server which is not the case here as the html is part of my application and will not be deployed on a server

Comment: What is the purpose of your html if it isn't sent to client ?

Comment: @Remi878 the html will appear in a window of my application and my application is using Google maps and an html plus JavaScript seemed the way to go. I would really like to leave it that way because it is too late to change the architecture of my program now

Comment: So the html is shown to the client (in a window of your applciation). Can't you make ajax request (with a simple servlet to get your result) ?

Comment: @Remi878 I am new to this and the technology i am using is JavaFX so i am loading the html using a WebEngine object. I do not know Java EE that well so i prefer to keep things in my realm of knowledge if possible

Comment: Why do you need the server to add two numbers together?  Why can't you just say `var myValue = value1 + value2;`?

Comment: @ach I assume that's just a simple example and there is a specific function `(double, double) -> double` that needs to be run.

Comment: @Phylogenesis yes that is correct, my application does some complex calculations but it all comes down to a function (double, double) - >double

Comment: @ciprianr Unfortunately, there's no nice way of doing this. If the HTML is dynamically generated by your Java application, you could precalculate the value required and set a JavaScript variable with the result. Other than that, as per Maurice Perry's answer, your only option is to create an HTTP service that responds to a SOAP/REST/XMLRPC request.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a very bad Idea.
I sometimes write java applications with an html user interface by starting an http server using the com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer API, then launching the browser at the correct URL with the Desktop.browse() method. I can expose (rest) web services that can be called from javascript.

Comment: Perhaps that is true but it is a little late to make changes know, especially since i really have not had any exposure to the HttpServer API. My application is in javaFX and everything that is complicated is done there. I just need to be able to access a function that will return a double based on two double parameters, that is the only thing i need the java integration for. It may be quick and dirty, but at this stage in my development phase and given the simplicity of the request, this is all i need.